# Why does excel calculate multiple workbooks faster than one big workbook?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I noticed that when I split my workbook with 10 sheets into 10 single workbooks, open them all, and calculate all simultanously with F9, the calculation is much faster finished than the calculation of the single workbook with 10 sheets. I find this behavior quite uncomfortable as the single workbook calculation takes really long while the split calculation is finished within seconds. Any idea why this is the case?

I use Excel 2016 and 32bit

Comment: Have you double checked if the results are correct in both cases? Are there no dependencies between the worksheets? These would get skipped if splitted in multiple workbooks.

Comment: About Excel Performance, these articles may be helpful: [Excel performance: Improving calculation performance](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/excel-performance/excel-improving-calculation-performance);[Excel performance: Performance and limit improvements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/excel-performance/excel-performance-and-limit-improvements);[Excel performance: Tips for optimizing performance obstructions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/excel-performance/excel-tips-for-optimizing-performance-obstructions).

Answer (score -1):

One way to see how your computer behaves in different scenarios is to open the "Performance" Tab in Task Manager during the execution. Set the CPU Graph "Logical Processors" with a right click on the graph and expanding "Change graph to >"

I suspect that the multiple workbooks will utilize the multiple cores of your CPU better.

Comment: This is what I am thinking. Do you think there might be a way to utilize multiple cores without splitting the workbook?

Comment: without digging too deep i found this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10/how-to-utilize-multiple-cores-in-excel-2016/76fef7bb-750d-42f7-95ca-91d2694479c1